# ObjectInputStream isn't finding any data to pull?

Tags: java, inputstream, objectinputstream

I am trying to read and write shape objects to a file for a drawing program, but when I try to read from the file it shows that the file is empty. The file is definitely being written to and updated, but when trying to read from the file it is showing that there are zero bytes available. The shape class is serializable so I am not sure why this isn't working at all.

```
public void writeToFile() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\johnm\\eclipse-workspace\\CSE205_Assignment05\\save.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            for (Shape item : shapes) {
                out.writeObject(item);
            }
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Serialized data is saved in output.ser");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void loadFromFile() {
        boolean cont = true;
        Shape shape = null;
        int count = 0;
        while (cont) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\johnm\\eclipse-workspace\\CSE205_Assignment05\\save.ser");
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
                System.out.println(in.available() + " Bytes");
                if (in.available() != 0) {
                    shape = (Shape) in.readObject();
                    if (shape != null) {
                        shapes.add(shape);
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Shape is null");
                    }
                } else {
                    cont = false;
                }
                in.close();
                fileIn.close();
                System.out.println("Deserialized " + count + " Objects");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
                System.out.println("Class not found");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright for some reason the .available() method isn't showing any bytes regardless of if there actually are any or not. To counter this I just threw in another try/catch statement where it continuously reads objects until it hits an EOFException and catches itself.

My code ended up looking like this once working.

```
public void loadFromFile() {
        //** Loads set of shape objects from file
        Shape shape = null;
        int count = 0;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("save.ser");
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            System.out.println(in.available() + " Bytes");
            try {
                while (true) {
                    shape = (Shape) in.readObject();
                    if (shape != null) {
                        shapes.add(shape);
                        count++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Shape is null");
                    }
                }
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                System.out.println("End of file exception");
            }
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
            System.out.println("Deserialized " + count + " Objects");
            repaint();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```